# SharePoint designer - Workflow Office365 + Online CRM

Tags: sharepoint, office365, dynamics-crm-online

This is my requirement, i know we can do it with webservices, but like to ensure whether there is any easy solution for that.

I have Office365 account, and i have created a public site in Office365. Lets say http://xyz.sharepoint.com is the site. I have online CRM account as well for the same windows live ID.

There is a feedback form on my office365 site. This is the page http://xyz.sharepoint.com/feedback.aspx. When user enter some content and click save button, i would like to save their eMail ID to online CRM. (Under leads section but not necessary, we can change it)

Is there any inbuild option to save the eMail to online CRM without code? Or i need to go for sandbox solution by using the webservices? Any good suggestion? How can i proceed with this.

Comment: By eMail do you actually mean a real email? E.g. is your form sending an email somewhere?

Comment: Hi James. User will fill the form and save it. There is no eMail sending. The details should be saved in online CRM. So i want to know how we can save the details from Office365 to Online CRM.

Comment: I think in this case then you will have to use mscrm webservices, as far as I know there is no inbult way to get data from sharepoint to crm. The reason I asked about email was because you could have the email sent to crm and converted by workflow.